# How to show/hide select when another select is selected

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

i'm so confused on how to hide and show a select element when another select is selected using jQuery. Here are my HTML code :

```
<tr>
    <td>Kategori Buku</td>
    <td>
        <select class="kategori-buku" name="kategori_buku">
            <option value=""><i>Pilih Kategori Buku</i></option>
            <option value="buku_pelajaran">Buku Pelajaran</option>
            <option value="buku_umum">Buku Umum</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="subkategori-buku-pelajaran">
    <td>Subkategori Buku</td>
    <td>
       <select class="subkategori-buku" name="subkategori_buku">
            <option value=""><i>Pilih Subkategori Buku</i></option>
            <option value="bahasa_indonesia">Bahasa Indonesia</option>
            <option value="biologi">Biologi</option>
            <option value="ekonomi">Ekonomi</option>
            <option value="fisika">Fisika</option>
            <option value="geografi">Geografi</option>
            <option value="kimia">Kimia</option>
            <option value="matematika">Matematika</option>
            <option value="sejarah">Sejarah</option>
            <option value="tik">TIK</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="subkategori-buku-umum">
    <td>Subkategori Buku</td>
    <td>
        <select class="subkategori-buku" name="subkategori_buku">
            <option value=""><i>Pilih Subkategori Buku</i></option>
            <option value="desain">Desain</option>
            <option value="pemrograman">Pemrograman</option>
            <option value="sistem_operasi">Sistem Operasi</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Based on my code above, i want to :

1. When **select.kategori-buku** isn't selected yet, **.subkategori-buku-pelajaran** table row and **.subkategori-buku-umum** table row will be hidden.
2. When option with value '*buku_pelajaran*' is selected in **select.kategori-buku**, the **.subkategori-buku-pelajaran** table row should be ***showed up*** and '**.subkategori-buku-umum**' table row ***should be hidden***.
3. When option with value '*buku_umum*' is selected in **select.kategori-buku**', the **.subkategori-buku-umum** table row should be ***showed up*** and '**.subkategori-buku-pelajaran**' table row ***should be hidden***.

I've used

> .val()

method using jQuery to get the **.kategori-buku**'s value then i used it to show/hide the **.subkategori**'s, but i'm fail. I appreciate any answer and help from you guys. Thank you before :)

**UPDATE**

---

These are my jQuery code :

```
$('.subkategori-buku-pelajaran').hide();
$('.subkategori-buku-umum').hide();

    var kategoriBuku = $('select.kategori-buku').val();

    if(kategoriBuku == '0'){
            $('.subkategori-buku-pelajaran').hide();
            $('.subkategori-buku-umum').hide();
    }
    elseif(kategoriBuku == 'buku_umum') {
        $('.subkategori-buku-umum').show();
    }
    elseif(kategoriBuku == 'buku_pelajaran') {
        $('.subkategori-buku-pelajaran').show();
    }
```

I think my code almost similar to PacMan's code, the diferrence are i don't use

> $('select.kategori-buku').change(function(){});

and

> var keyword

Anyway, big thanks for Kris and PacMan. I really appreciate your helps :D

Comment: Please show your attempted jQuery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand very well your situation , this piece of code might help you more !!
//by default the .subkategori-buku-umum and the select.kategori-buku they will be hidden so in the css you can make just

```
.kategori-buku , .subkategori-buku-umum{display : none}
```

and now you will inject some JS code to animate things here is my approach :

```
$('select.kategori-buku').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val === "buku_pelajaran"){
            $('.subkategori-buku-pelajaran').show();
            $('.subkategori-buku-umum').hide();
        }else if(val === "buku_umum"){
            $('.subkategori-buku-pelajaran').hide();
            $('.subkategori-buku-umum').show();
        }
    });
```

i hope it helped a little bit .

Comment: I'm glad cause it helped :D

Comment: Kris's (http://stackoverflow.com/users/18565/kris) code helped me. And i've just tried your code, and your code works well too, thanks for your help. I really appreciate it :D

Comment: P.S : I add '$('.subkategori-buku-pelajaran').hide();
                  $('.subkategori-buku-umum').hide();' code before 'change' method in order to make your code works. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd work with something like this:

```
$('select').change(function(){

    var search = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr('rel');
    var all = $('.hide-on-select').show();
    var hide = $('[rel="'+search+'"]').hide();

});
```

then add the 'hide-on-select' class to all elements i wanted hidden and link various `rel` attributes.

*This is typed in a textarea and intended to convey an idea not provide a working implementation*

**additional:**

It seemed like fun so [I fiddled' it](https://jsfiddle.net/theredhead/p82z9g3L/1/) and made it a bit simpler then I initially thought:

```
$('.sub').hide();
$('select.kategori-buku').change(function() {
  var search = 'subkategori-' + ($(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).val().replace('_', '-'));
  $('.sub').hide();
  $('.sub.'+search).show();
});
```

I also added two `.sub` classes in the html on the `tr` elements.

Comment: Thanks, man! Your code work for me :D And now i just need to learn and understand your code more. Thanks for your help, dude :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any JQuery in your post

Every HTML object has an attribute `hidden`. You can use Javascript/JQuery to check what is selected and then hide the rest.

Comment: Sorry i forget to post it. But Kris (http://stackoverflow.com/users/18565/kris) and PacMan's (http://stackoverflow.com/users/5576082/pacman) code helped me. Thanks anyway :D